# jQuery not animating from top-bottom effect when animating height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to create a vertical height animation in jQuery and it has a very strange effect where as, in the best terms I can explain it are:

height of div is 100px, animation starts at ~15px in and animates outwards up 15px and then down 85px rather than just up 100px.

NOTE: I have tried removing the negative margin, it doesn't fix the issue.

Here is my css

```
.content {
width: 60%;
margin: 0 auto; }

.content .bar {
height: 0px;
width: 20px;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: -5px; }

.content span {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
opacity: 0; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="10">
            <div class="bar red"></div>
            <span>Content goes here</span>
        </div>
        <div class="20">
            <div class="bar blue"></div>
            <span>Content goes here</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using jQuery UI for other elements in my webpage.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. Which element are you trying to animate?

Comment: I'm trying to animate .bar